# How to show large code samples in reveal.js?

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

I often have code samples in reveal.js slide decks that span quite many lines.

Take for instance the markdown code as example:

````
---
title: "Long and silly code"
author: "Yours truly"
---

```python
print('1')
print('2')
print('fizz')
print('4')
print('buzz')
print('fizz')
print('7')
print('8')
print('fizz')
print('buzz')
print('11')
print('fizz')
print('13')
print('14')
print('fizzbuzz')
print('16')
print('17')
```
````

Once rendered, it will look like this, with a scroll bar:

[image]

The code block seems to always have a max height, and past a certain number of lines a scrollbar appears, even though I'd prefer just a larger box.

I have not yet figured out how to make the box larger both vertically and horizontally so to fill the available slide area rather than scrolling: I have no interest in pausing my presentation to scroll with the mouse just to show more code!

Does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: I don't see why this question has been closed. Reveal.js is 'programming' a slideshow with HTML / CSS / JS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The css provided by Reveal.js seems [responsible for the vertical limit](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/cb9e507cd43dce2f118a7ae78a76bf8d6e2bf3ba/css/reveal.css#L339).
Hence it seems you have no choice, but to tweak the css yourself.

For example, modify the file `css/reveal.css` (and regenerate `css/reveal.min.css`).

Or you could try to override this value with an additional theme you would provide. For example, copy `css/theme/default.css` to `css/theme/mine.css`, define the style you want for the code blocks, and link to this file in the `<head>` of your `.html` presentation file.

Comment: In case anyone ends up here: The specific CSS is `max-height` set on `.reveal pre code`. Just overwrite this value with your own CSS rules and either set it to a larger value or to `initial`.

Comment: is this still a valid answer?

Comment: Now there's a `stretch` class that you can put on code blocks

Comment: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/72b05a3245479dd46ed10bdb81437f8eb01f23c1/README.md#stretching-elements

Comment: Just to summarise, there are two options:
1. overwrite the CSS value of `max-height` for `.reveal pre code`. The default value is in the theme `.css`, which is `400px`.
2. add a `stretch` class to `pre`. adding `stretch` class to `code` will make the code overflows and is not scrollable.

Comment: Height works fine but how can we change the width of this code block?